# Application stops due to XML file

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an application that displays data in ExpandableListView layout. The application is stopped after I click on the GroupItem. My GroupItem has image icon and indicator. If I remove the image from the GroupItem, it works perfect. So I'm assuming there is something wrong with my group.xml, but I couldn't figure out.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/group_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat:

```
06-04 19:52:51.562: I/Choreographer(4599): Skipped 172 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-04 19:52:58.020: D/AndroidRuntime(4599): Shutting down VM
06-04 19:52:58.020: W/dalvikvm(4599): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-04 19:52:58.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4599): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 19:52:58.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4599): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 19:52:58.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4599):     at com.example.wip.ExpandableListViewAdapter.getGroupView(ExpandableListViewAdapter.java:142)
06-04 19:52:58.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4599):     at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:446)
```

According to Logcat, I got NullPointException in line 142 where I set the image.

```
holder.mIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
```

Java Code:

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        GroupViewHolder holder = new GroupViewHolder();
        if (convertView == null) {  
            convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.grouprow, null);  
            holder.mIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        }  
        holder.mIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.cvsm);


        holder.mGroupName = (TextView) convertView  
                .findViewById(R.id.group_name);  
        holder.mGroupName.setText(groupItem.get(groupPosition));  

        return convertView;  


    }

private class GroupViewHolder {
        ImageView mIcon ; 
        TextView mGroupName;  
    }
```

Comment: Post the logcat and relevant java code

Comment: I see no wrong with xml. post your code

Comment: What is at line 142 of `ExpandableListViewAdapter`? You likely aren't initializing your `ImageView` properly

Comment: where I set the image. Does it mean I click the image and cause the nullpointerexception?

Comment: Yes. Show where you initialize the `ImageView`. `mIcon` is `null`

Comment: @Michael try this holder.mIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon); check if mIcon is null or not.

Comment: @Raghunandan Yeah,same excepetion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move

```
GroupViewHolder holder = new GroupViewHolder();
```

inside your `if` statement. You are creating a new instance each time which makes `mIcon` `null` everytime. It should be like

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    GroupViewholder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {  
        holder = new GroupViewHolder();  // try putting it here
        convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.grouprow, null);  
        holder.mIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. The application works perfect without this line holder.mIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

Comment: Have you tried it? It should solve the problem because you are initializing your other `holder` variable before using it but you aren't initializing that one

Comment: I have to setText outside of the if statement.  holder.mGroupName.setText(groupItem.get(groupPosition)); This line should also cause exception error if I don't have the setImage code. But it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, but you initialize it right before so it isn't `null`
`holder.mGroupName = (TextView) convertView  
                .findViewById(R.id.group_name);  `

Comment: Yes, causes exception When I run the application

Comment: And what is that exception, the same? Check to see if `mIcon` is `null` but I'm sure it is the way it was

Comment: Problem solved. I moved holder.mIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img) outside of the If statement.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it but that doesn't make sense unless your `convertView` is never `null` so it doesn't enter the `if`. In which case, your `Holder` class is useless/

Comment: GroupViewHolder holder;if (convertView == null) {  
         holder = new GroupViewHolder();...}. try this

Comment: Oh, your `Holder` class should be `static`

Comment: Yes, that's right @Raghunandan I was thinking that but I was waiting for a reply on the exception before editing. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If my mind was in just one place you would have had it sooner :p